# How to fix a Connection Error Status 0?

Tags: technical-issues, star-wars-commander

I've started to play Star Wars: Commander on my phone (Samsung Galaxy A5 2017) but I literally can't do anything without "Connection Error - Status 0 (then telling me to check my Internet connection)". My Internet connection is perfectly fine - I'd even move closer to the WiFi router to get a better connection but it made no difference.

I also play it on my Galaxy Tab A6 and it works fine - been playing on it since December 2017. I still get the odd connection errors on the tablet but it has never been as bad as it is on my phone.

How can I fix this?? My WiFi seems fine.

Answer (score -1):

Have you used that phone so much?
If so , then that means that you have used a lot of data, so try leaving it for a couple of days and try again or maybe enjoy your game  on your Galaxy Tab A6.

Comment: Alright, thanks. I think you're right with the data. I'll just see how it goes.

Comment: 2 days later - unfortunately, nothing changed ; (